# Is there an platform independent equivalent of os.startfile()?

Tags: python, platform

I want to run a program on several platforms (including Mac OS), so I try to keep it as platform independent as possible. I use Windows myself, and I have a line `os.startfile(file)`. That works for me, but not on other platforms (I read in the documentation, I haven't tested for myself).

Is there an equivalent that works for all platforms?

By the way, the file is a `.wav` file, but I want users to be able to use their standard media player, so they can pause/rewind the file. That's why I use `os.startfile()`. I might be able to work with libraries that also allow playing/pausing/rewinding media files.

Comment: Try : http://www.pygame.org/project-Python+Media+Player-185-.html

Comment: related: [Start Another Program From Python >Separately<](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13078071/4279)

Comment: I just felt this was an excellent time to advertise my package, pyquark, which has an OS-independent way of doing this. You can install it with `pip install` pyquark  and then `import pyquark pyquark.filestart('file.file')`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It appears that a cross-platform file opening module does not yet exist, but you can rely on existing infrastructure of the popular systems. This snippet covers Windows, MacOS and Unix-like systems (Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris...):

```
import os, sys, subprocess

def open_file(filename):
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        os.startfile(filename)
    else:
        opener = "open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
        subprocess.call([opener, filename])
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope this works. I will accept your answer as soon as I can test the program on other platforms.

Comment: For Windows, the quotations around the filename should be omitted. Does this matter for other platforms?

Comment: @Lewistrick Without the quotes files with spaces in file or directory name won't work, which is always a bug waiting to happen. I've now edited the answer to simply use `os.startfile` on Win32, and open/xdg-open elsewhere. Now that Windows is handled separately, the code can use `subprocess.call` to handle file names with spaces or special characters. (On Windows `start` is part of `cmd`, so `subprocess.call` without `shell=True` wouldn't work.)

Comment: Thanks! Can I do a similar thing for deleting files? For both Windows and Unix I can use `os.remove()`, and if I'm right, MacOS uses `rm` for removing. Can I use `subprocess.call(["rm", filename])` in MacOS?

Comment: @Lewistrick `os.remove` will work on all three OS-es, so I suggest that you stick to that. MacOS is in most lower-level things close to a POSIX system.

Comment: I should've looked that up. It says somewhere else that MacOS counts as Unix when using `os.remove` :)

Comment: @user4815162342: what happens if you run `python -mwebbrowser some.wav` on your system?

Comment: @user4815162342: I infer that it works on your system. Thank you.

Comment: @user4815162342 This is a good answer, but not great, because it emits a warning in syntax checkers like pylint: `Module 'os' has no 'startfile' member (no-member)`

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan That should be reported as a bug to the syntax checker maintainers, since `startfile` is a [documented member of `os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile) on Windows.

Comment: @user4815162342 It is, on Windows, but not on Unix, where the software might be developed and syntax-checked. Adding checks to syntax checkers whether a statement is invoked only on an execution path in case of a specific system would be too complicated I think.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan My point is that the checker software has no place warning against the use of a documented function. It's a bug in the checker, not in the code that invokes `os.startfile`.

Comment: Surprisingly, this is not in any library in Pypi (that I have seen)

Comment: I just felt this was an excellent time to advert py package, pyquark, witch has a OS - independant way of doing this. You can install it with `pip install pyquark ` and then `import pyquark pyquark.filestart('file.file')`

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`webbrowser.open(filename)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html). it can call `os.startfile()`, `open`, `xdg-open` where appropriate.

Beware, there is a [scary text in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open):

> Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this
>   function, may work and start the operating system’s associated
>   program. However, this is neither supported nor portable.

It works fine for me. Test it in your environment.

Look at [`webbrower`'s source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/656d0e273ccb/Lib/webbrowser.py#l412) to see how much work needs to be done to be portable.

There is also an open issue on Python bug tracker -- [Add shutil.open](http://bugs.python.org/issue3177). "portable os.startfile()" interface turned out to be more complex than expected. You could try the submitted patches e.g., [`shutil.launch()`](http://bugs.python.org/file25311/shutil_launch.py).

Comment: This won't work on OS X. On both Python 2.7 and Python 3, this returns `True` but doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @LukeTaylor I believe webbrowser  uses `open` command on OS X. If it doesn't work for you then create a minimal code example and post it as a separate question.

Comment: It's not a big concern for me, I just wanted to let you know.

Comment: @LukeTaylor without a specific code example that reproduces the issue; it is not very useful. Is it hard to write: `python -m webbrowser my.wav`  and describe what is happening, mention your OS, python versions. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

It depend what you mean with platform independent. If your question is about how to open *anything* using the default action of the OS, for example, when you double click on some file to let the OS decide how to open it, then the simple answer is **no**.

However, to implement this functionality yourself, is very easy, but you need to use a few different methods to accommodate for different OS's. That said, the most forgiving method is to use `os.system(WinPathWithArgs)` as I have explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53127976/1147688).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["open", 'directory'])
```

Comment: It's working for mac os to open any directory(Folder)