# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to run this [program](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216929/saving-a-tkinter-canvas-drawing-python), I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "piltk.py", line 84, in <module>
    os.startfile(filename)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: That seems to be a Windows only function, are you using Windows?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Linux you can use:

```
import subprocess, sys

opener = "open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
subprocess.call([opener, filename])
```

Adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17317468/1079363)

Comment: In case it's not obvious, this answer works for macOS too (that's what "darwin" means).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are not running on Windows you cannot use `os.startfile`.  If you want to launch another process you could use `os.system` or look at the `subprocess` module

Comment: 3 years later, still nothing that properly documents this, while still talking about using windows paths in the [same doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.startfile).

Comment: @not2qubit if you look at the bottom of that description you link to you can see it says "Availability: Windows" which is how it documents for each function which platforms you can expect it to work on (contrast with os.system right below it that has "Availability: Unix, Windows")

Comment: That is what I was saying. It claim to work on Windows, but doesn't, at least not for me on Python3.6.

Comment: @not2qubit you might need to start a new question then, I just downloaded the latest 3.7.1 for Windows and it worked fine to open a word document with word for me

Comment: Hm, ok, perhaps I'm not using it right then. Can you provide a usage example?

Comment: @not2qubit I just did `os.startfile(r'c:\Users\erenouf\Documents\resume.odt')` and it launched Word to edit that file

Answer (score 1):

Maybe so:
os.system('xdg-open аny_file')