# line 21, in <module> os.startfile(fileName) AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'startfile'

Tags: python, python-requests

line 21, in 
os.startfile(fileName)
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'startfile'

On mac and each time this happens

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both from now; probably [edit] to clarify which one you are using, and how you installed it if it's not the one which shipped with the OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823028/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-startfile)

Comment: According to the documentation,  `os.startfile()` is available only on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Like [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) clearly states, `os.startfile()` is Windows only.

Comment: how do i do it in a mac then

Comment: Did you read the linked duplicate?