# pythonmp3 file open error in Mac Os X

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm using `os.startfile` code to run  `.mp3` file but there is an error:

My code is

```
os.system("Warning.mp3")
```

but i get an error like this,

```
sh: Warning.mp3: command not found
```

can you help me about starting mp3 file using os.startfile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an platform independent equivalent of os.startfile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317219/is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile)

Comment: The `os.startfile` function is [Windows-only](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).