# How to Create Tkinter Button that Links to Textfile

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, text-files

I need a button which the user can click which will open a textfile called "project tkinter.txt" (which is already existing).

I tried this suggestion another user had:

```
def opencopypaste():
    from os import startfile
    startfile("c:\\path\\to\\file") # i put the file path here #

openbutton = Button(frame, text='click me', command=opencopypaste)
openbutton.grid()
```

However, it says it cannot find "startfile" in os.py. Then I tried another suggestion which was:

```
def opencopypaste():
    webbrowser.open("project tkinter.txt")
```

This time the code ran and created a button, however clicking on the button did nothing. I can't seem to find any way to create a hyperlink or button to a textfile in tkinter. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an platform independent equivalent of os.startfile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317219/is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile)

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on Mac or Linux? Because if it is the case [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317219/is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile/17317468#17317468) could be helpful.

Comment: yes i am, and that question completely solved my problem! thank you so much! for some reason i never saw that, thank you so much for sharing!