# TKinter to open a word file in a new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a tool to filter a profile based on skills and then finally open a word document with detailed information on the selected profile.

I am using Tkinter to show the dropdown menu for each filter.

Below is my Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from pandas import * 
import os

root=Tk()
root.title('Skill Search Tool')

def getProfile():
    
    os.system("SelectedProfile.docx")


ProfileGet= Button(root,text="Get Profile",command=getProfile())
ProfileGet.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

However when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Can anyone guide me here?

Regards,
Chinmay

Comment: You need to pass the function reference `command=getProfile`, not the result of the function `command=getProfile()`.

Comment: Also better use `os.startfile(...)` instead of `os.system(...)` in your case if your platform is Windows.

Comment: I am working on a Mac. I tried to change the code from command=getProfile() to command=getProfile and the function definition to def getProfile():
    name="SelectedProfile.docx"
    os.system(name) but now I am getting another error when I click on the button. sh: SelectedProfile.docx: command not found

Comment: It is because `os.system()` will treat `SelectedProfile.docx` as command.  As I don't know about MacOS, you need to find a way to open the .docx using default program.

Comment: Maybe [is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317219/is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function `getProfiles` when you add the brackets to the end which means it will run as soon as your program starts, instead you can simply write...

`ProfileGet= Button(root,text="Get Profile",command=getProfile)`

However, if in the future you wish to pass parameters to your function you may want to use a lambda function...

```
ProfileGet= Button(root,text="Get Profile",command=lambda: getProfile(arg1,arg2))
```