# How To Create WIFI splash page Using Python

Tags: python, html

It Is Possible To Create Wifi Splash Page Using Python ???

When Someone Connect My WIFI Automatically Load My HTML Page to connected device 
AnyOne Have An Idea Please Answer

Comment: do you want open page in browser after someone connect your WIFI? what is your host OS?

Comment: Your access point has to support a captive portal.

Comment: I Using Windows OS , Router - TPlink

Answer (score 2):

In linux you need install Nmap ("Network Mapper"):

`sudo apt install nmap`

and

`pip3 install who-is-on-my-wifi`

This code scans and write html than open it, you can make it with `if conditions` and `while`:

```
import who_is_on_my_wifi
import subprocess, sys

WHO = who_is_on_my_wifi.who()
body = ''

for i in range(0, len(WHO)):
    body += '<p>' + ' '.join(WHO[i]) + '</p>\n' 

page = f'''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  {body}
</body>
</html>'''

with open("connections.html", "w") as write_file:
   write_file.write(page)

# opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"    
# break with sudo:     subprocess.call([opener, 'connections.html'])

subprocess.call(['sudo', '-u', 'daniil', 'xdg-open', 'wifi.html'])
```

When you run without sudo it shows only your IP :(

`sudo python3 wifi.py`

on browser you can see:

[image]

Comment: Thank You For Your Answer But How Can I Run it on windows ??

Comment: read this for installation https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html and run sript as administator

Comment: for open page os.startfile('connections.html') read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317219/is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile

Comment: DHCP Hijacking Is Posible Or Not Using Python