# Python open OS' file explorer on file location

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I open Finder.app (on macOS), explorer.exe (on Windows), Gnome or similar (user's choice? on Linux) into a folder with a file highlighted using Python.

In macOS terminal

```
open -R /path/to/file
```

reveals the file in Finder.

In Windows

```
explorer /select,"C:\path\to\file"
```

seems to do the same thing.

What's the most reliable cross-platform implementation that is available in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an platform independent equivalent of os.startfile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317219/is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile)

Comment: @Marat it's a different question, but the top answer is helpful. Didn't know I only had to check `sys.platform` against win32 and darwin

Comment: @Marat xdg-open doesn't seem to have a reveal-file option?

Comment: as far as I know, it doesn't.