# os module start file is not working in my linux operating system

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, module, operating-system

```py
def open_img(self):
            try:
                os.startfile("Data")
            except Exception as es:
                messagebox.showerror("Error",f" due to : {str(es)}",parent=self.root)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please include your code and format your post to include the full traceback error.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317219/is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile

Answer (score 1):

`os.startfile` is explicitly only available under Windows per the docs
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile

> Availability: Windows.

Comment: then how to open any file in linux

Comment: is there any another function like startfile for linux operating system

Comment: while this is surely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), take a look at the duplicate mark! `xdg-open` is likely what you're after

Comment: can we use xdg-open in vscode for any operation

Comment: you can use `xdg-open` to start the program associated with its argument type (in your case, perhaps a directory) Microsoft VSCode is irrelevant