# How do I open a file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to open a random mp3 file using python so that I can play a random song from my music playlist.

these are two variations of the code that I have tried

```
file = str('C:\file.mp3')
open(file)
```

or

```
open('C:\file.mp3')
```

When I run the program, I expect to see the Microsoft mp3 player to open and for the file to play but instead I get a pop-up message saying `"Unicode error: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape".`

I have never used `open()` before so if it is something very simple then I'm sorry.

Comment: "I expect to see the Microsoft mp3 player to open" why? Also, documentation -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: on some systems you can use `import webbrowser`; `webbrowser.open(filename)` to open this file with default program in system. If you need to open in different program then you may need `os.system("your_player.exe your_file.mp3")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use raw strings for Windows file paths (and regexes). Otherwise, a folder whose name begins with `U` (say, `C:\Users`) ends up looking like the beginning of a Unicode escape; many other characters end up being interpreted as escapes as well (e.g. `f` is escaped to the form feed character).

Using raw strings (prefixed with `r`) means backslashes only escape the quote character, nothing else. So:

```
with open(r'C:\file.mp3') as f:
```

works, where:

```
with open('C:\file.mp3') as f:
```

wouldn't. That said, none of this would open the file in your music player. `open` opens the raw file to read data from it (odds are an `mp3` file will error if you try to read it in text mode, unless you're using one of the more permissive codecs, like `latin-1`). If you want to *launch* a file via its default handler, [that's what `os.startfile` is for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile), e.g.:

```
os.startfile(r'C:\file.mp3')
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before. A link to the documentation [can be found here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile)

Please see [Can Python Open a MP3 File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198604/can-python-open-a-mp3-file).

You can use the built in `os` library:

```
import os
os.startfile('my_mp3.mp3')
```